# Google Cloud - Redis Alternative for managing Queues?

Tags: redis, google-cloud-platform, queue, google-cloud-memorystore

I'm looking for a Google Cloud based solution that can provide a fast and safe way to pop or fill Queues from multiple threads/processes.

Basically, I have a list of unique items, and I need a low-latency solution to select an item from it only once to a user (whenever the user requests one).

A pattern like Redis List/pop is perfect for that, but I'm open to any other solution that can achieve the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way to achieve this is, or is about to become, Google’s own Cloud Memorystore: https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/

> Cloud Memorystore for Redis provides a fully managed in-memory data store service built on scalable, more secure, and highly available infrastructure managed by Google.

Comment: Also expensive. 35$/month minimum

Comment: @Aseem what you think about installing redis on a free tier VM instance instead?